# GridSearchCV unexpected behaviour (always returns the first parameter as the best)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I've got a multiclass classification problem and I need to find the best parameters. I cannot change the `max_iter`, `solver`, and `tol` (they are given), but I'd like to check which `penalty` is better. However, `GridSearchCV` always returns the first given penalty as the best one.

Example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0, shuffle=True)

fixed_params = {
    'random_state': 42,
    'multi_class': 'multinomial',
    'solver': 'saga',
    'tol': 1e-3,
    'max_iter': 500
}

parameters = [
    {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2', None]},
    {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'penalty': ['elasticnet'], 'l1_ratio': np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)}     
]

model = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(**fixed_params), parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10, scoring='f1_macro' ,cv=cv)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model.best_score_)
# 0.6836409100287101

print(model.best_params_)
# {'C': 0.1, 'penalty': 'l2'}
```

If I change the order of `parameters`  rows, the result will be quite opposite:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
    
fixed_params = {
    'random_state': 42,
    'multi_class': 'multinomial',
    'solver': 'saga',
    'tol': 1e-3,
    'max_iter': 500
}

parameters = [
        {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'penalty': ['elasticnet'], 'l1_ratio': np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)} 
        {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2', None]}          
]
    
model = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(**fixed_params), parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10, scoring='f1_macro' ,cv=cv)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model.best_score_)
# 0.6836409100287101

print(model.best_params_)
# {'C': 0.1, 'l1_ratio': 0.0, 'penalty': 'elasticnet'}
```

So, the `best_score_` is the same for both options, but the `best_params_` is not.

Could you please tell me what is wrong?

**Edited**
GridSearchCV gives a worse result in comparison to baseline with default parameters.
**Baseline:**

```
baseline_model = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='saga', tol=1e-3, max_iter=500)
baseline_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
train_pred_baseline = baseline_model.predict(X_train)
print(f1_score(y_train, train_pred_baseline, average='micro'))
```

> LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False,
> fit_intercept=True,
> intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=500,
> multi_class='multinomial', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
> random_state=None, solver='saga', tol=0.001, verbose=0,
> warm_start=False)

Baseline gives me f1_micro better than  GridSearchCV:

```
0.7522768670309654
```

**Edited-2**
So, according to best `f1_score` performance, `C = 1` is the best choice for my model. But GridSearchCV returns me `C = 0.1`.
I think, I miss something...
Baseline's `f1_macro` better than GridSearchCV too:

```
    train_pred_baseline = baseline_model.predict(X_train)
    print(f1_score(y_train, train_pred_baseline, average='macro'))
    # 0.7441968750050458
```

Comment: You can try to debug it by looking at all GridSearch's results ( check `model.cv_results_`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there's nothing wrong. Here's the thing. Elasticnet uses both L1 and L2 penalty terms. However, if your `l1_ratio` is 0, then you're basically applying L2 regularization so you're only using the L2 penalty term. As stated in the docs:

> Setting `l1_ratio=0` is equivalent to using `penalty='l2'`, while setting `l1_ratio=1` is equivalent to using `penalty='l1'`. For `0 < l1_ratio <1`, the penalty is a combination of L1 and L2.

Since your second result had `l1_ratio` to be 0, it's equivalent to using L2 penalty terms.

Comment: could you please tell me, why GridSearchCV gives me f1_score worse than baseline? (I edited my question).

Comment: With default settings, I've got f1 score_micro = 0.75, but after  GridSearchCV only 0.68. The Baseline better for my test sample too...

Comment: You're using `f1_macro` as your scorer for grid search but your baseline uses `f1_micro`. Also take into consideration that grid search uses cross validation so part of the training set is held out per CV split where the held-out samples are scored and averaged.

Comment: my fault, but the problem is still with me, f1_macro is better for the baseline too.

Comment: is a good idea to change CV parameters?

Comment: Again, this is the result of training with grid search and training without any cross validation. In addition, my guess is that your baseline model was trained with `X_train` and then scored using your `X_train`. You actually should not be doing this in practice because you're testing it on data you already used to train your model with. You should have a `X_test` sample and test both your models on that sample set to get a fair comparison.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make X_val sample and try.